# SiteCatalyst transactionID Data Source Order submission

Tags: tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

we are struggling upon make imported orders unique, through a **transactionID Data Source template**.

In fact, this template does not consider a "purchaseID" column, and it does not parse this variable if we force it into the template.
At the moment, we set **one row for every product purchased by the same "transactionID customer"**, with the addictional fields below:

Date  Evar 22  Category  Product  Orders  Quantity  transactionID
06/06/2015 evar_value category product_name 1 1 123456
06/06/2015 evar_value category2 product_name2 1 2 123456
... ... ... ... .. .. ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...

This example will produce 2 Orders for the "123456" customer, even if it's the same one including 3 Units (Quantity) of 2 products.
So we expected just 1 Order for this customer.
We supposed the transactionID could be a unique key, working as the purchaseID, but it does not.

Then we tried to put all the products in the same row, removing the Category column and exploiting the "s.products" format, as below:

06/06/2015 evar_value **category;product_name,category2;product_name2** 1 2 123456

Now the Quantity field gets 2 units.
With this template we were closer to the goal, because the Order was correctly recognized as unique.
The issue here concerns the Products, because Data Source always seems to expect an addictional one as the first.
In this example, beside "product_name" and "product_name2" an "**Unspecified**" product will be reported.

To sum up: how Orders could be recognized as unique when imported through transactionID, but irrespective of template (default or custom)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full processing data sources in this case as it will bind order to visitor.

Workaround

If you want to use this template then in first column pass 1 against order and against other pass 0 each.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @shamshul2007 for the suggestions. On the first, unfortunately we can't use the full processing because it doesn't parse the transactionID column that's critical in this case, we tried it. Regarding the second option you mention, it's not clear to me how you would pass 0 for columns which need values...(eVar, Quantity, etc...)..? Thx

Comment: Yes in full processing Transaction ID can't be parsed so you can use visitor ID.Visitor IDs can be integrated by selecting the Generic (Transaction ID) category.

Comment: Thanks @shamshul2007 but passing the Visitor ID is not my target, even because we are not using s.visitorID in our tracking strategy (unique users are tracked by the default cookie). We must focus on the transactionID model.